# Mxgraph overlay event listener broken after file save / load

Tags: javascript, events, mxgraph

I have the following code in my mxgraph project:

```
var overlay = new mxCellOverlay(
  new mxImage(mxIcons.GREY.FILE_TEXT, 18, 18),
  null, mxConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT, mxConstants.ALIGN_TOP, new mxPoint(8, -8), 'default');

cell.note = overlay;
graph.addCellOverlay(cell, overlay);

// toggle the text box on and off with icon click
overlay.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, evt)
{
    if (overlay.textBox.visible)
        graph.getModel().setVisible(overlay.textBox, false);
    else
        graph.getModel().setVisible(overlay.textBox, true);
});
```

This works fine, but when I save the file then load it I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at mxCellOverlay.mxEventSource.fireEvent (mxEventSource.js:185)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (mxCellRenderer.js:601)
```

when clicking on the overlay icon. Inspecting the overlay shows me that the listener is still attached. I can't figure out what has changed to break this.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to save and load from file? Maybe something is breaking references there...

Comment: It's quite long but the only part referencing the overlay just checks if `cell.note` exists and if it does it adds the overlay.

Comment: I assume you are saving to XML... It is difficult to answer... In my view, the most likely place where something wrong is happening is when you save and then restore the graph... But without seeing the code it is impossible to tell...